# Talend: Handle order of columns

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, talend, data-integration

I am designing a job in Talend (ETL Tool). The incoming Data may have columns in different order.

How do I handle this? I want to map them to a static target (I am using tMap for this). 
Also, I need to take care of number of columns(it may be less or more than what is expected)

Answer (score 1):

check this tutorial. It works perfectly:

http://bekwam.blogspot.de/2011/06/dynamic-schemas-in-talend-open-studio.html

Comment: Please avoid link only answers. Instead try to quote the relevant parts that would answer the question and then link to the outside source for further information if the reader needs it.

Comment: ah. you mean copy content from other sources to stackoverflow? what about copyright then?

Comment: As long as you link back to the original source then there's no copyright issues as far as I know although I am not a lawyer. One of the rules of answering in Stack Overflow is that your answer should completely answer the relevant question with out relying on a link working.

Answer (score 0):

tFilterColumn can be used for filter columns flow from one component to another. Even tmap itself is a good way to control number of columns in output table of tmap.